# PHPExcel - saving images while modify spreadsheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm reading spreadsheet and change values of some cells, then save it with

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPexcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('write.xls');
```

But it doesn't save any images. 
How to transfer images from original file to new? 
We can get images `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection()` but how put this into new file?

Comment: As all you're showing is the save code, it doesn't really give any clues.... how are you loading the file? Are you saving with the same name? Are you copying worksheets? What are you doing that might affect the images?

Comment: I tried just open input file, and save it to output file. And there are no images in output file.  `$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inFile);  
 $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');  $objWriter->save($outFile);`

Comment: What does the IOFactory identify the file as? Call `PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inFile);` and echo the result.

Comment: The result is `Excel2007`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the reason of lost images. They have been copied to excel from .doc directly, when I paste images to excel through menu they've been saved in output file.

Comment: grave dig.. but im having this same problem, except it wont save even after i put the image in there myself though excel via the insert image option... did you try anything else different ?